# Voxeo IVR tool always takes CXML instead of VXML

Tags: vxml

I am currently working on Voxeo tool for VXML testing. After installing modified vxml-home and in URL1   "http://127.0.0.1:9990/acup.xml" to test my xml.
Instead of taking acup.xml when I dial it always took callxml-home.xml(CXML).
If I remove CXML file then it does not play any files it error will be played.

Error:
"Error 601 application which you are looking cannot be located."

why voxeo everytime pick CXML am I missing some configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Contact the Voxeo support... or try Asterisk/Voximal it is more simple for a trial and it is free for 1 port with full features.